# trying to make icons fixed with css

Tags: html, css

```css
h4 {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 10px;
}

i {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left" id="prev" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h4 class="quotes" style="display:inline-block;">
    Web Devloper
    </h4>
    <h4 class="quotes" style="display:inline-block;">
    Web Designer
    </h4>
    <h4 class="quotes" style="display:inline-block;">
    Freelancer
    </h4>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" id="next" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

How do I make the next and previous icons stay fixed? Here's the problem:

[image]

Comment: Why not give a fixed width for `.quotes` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add to icons `position: absolute;` and for parent element `position: relative;`. For example:

```css
#block {
  padding: 20px 70px;
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
#prev, #next {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
}
#prev {left: 20px;}
#next {right: 20px;}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div id="next"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <div id="prev"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use floats

```
#prev {float:left;} 
#next {float:right;}
```

or absolute positioning

```
#prev {position:absolute;left:0;}
#next {position:absolute;right:0;}
```

or possibly a flexbox approach, something like

```
.col-md-12 {display:flex;width:100%;}
h4 {flex:1 0 auto;}
#prev,#next {flex:0 0 auto;}
```